# android java R.string.xxxx gives wrong value

Tags: android, string, getresource

I am calling the following
context.getResources().getString(R.string.last_call)

In my string file i have amongst others

```
<string name="last_call">Last Call</string>
<string name="language">Preferred language</string>
```

Instead of seeing "Last Call" as expected I am getting Preferred language

How is this possible????

Comment: Do a clean and rebuild - sometimes the compiled resource IDs get messed up when you add or remove things.